# Powershell - reading input file and adding a directory

Tags: powershell, file-io

I need to make sub-directories in folder `C:\projects`.  I am reading the input file using get-content -Raw to convert the file into a string and then splitting the string at newline.  But when I pass the strings to New-Item, it says "Illegal characters in path".  I even used trim() to trim white space, or newline characters but I get the same error.

```
$inputTxt = Get-Content "c:\input.txt" -Raw 
[string[]]$input = $inputTxt.split("`n")
$combinePath = "c:\projects"+ "\" + $input[$i]

New-Item $combinePath -type directory
```

Alternatively, I was just reading the input file directly into an array using get-content but without -Raw parameter, which splits on newline, but problem occurs when there is only 1 input in the file, then it splits the string according to characters instead of newline.

Comment: What is `$i`? Have you tried printing `$combinePath` before `New-Item` to see what exactly is getting passed in?

Comment: I have stored the strings in the $input array. It is in a for loop, $i indexes into the array (I didn't the paste that code).  Yes I am printing it, it looks fine.  THat's why I thought maybe there were some escape characters in the path, so I used trim() and that didn't work

Comment: Please add some sample of `$combinePath` when it fails

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `-Raw`. The default behavior of `Get-Content` is to give you an array of lines.  You just need to filter for empty lines and lines with illegal path chars e.g.:

```
$inputTxt = Get-Content C:\input.txt | Where {$_.Trim().Length -gt 0}
$inputTxt -replace '[<>|"]','' | Foreach {New-Item (Join-Path c:\projects $_) -type directory}
```

That isn't the complete list of invalid chars but should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I tried this, but if the input txt has only one input such as 133, instead of creating c:\projects\133, it creates c:\projects\1  ,c:\projects\3 , c:\projects\3.  I wonder why it does this

Comment: I can't repro that.  It works as-is for me on V3. In your case, it acts like it is enumerating the characters in the string rather than treating the string as a single object.